# A question on the completely positive maps and manifold structure

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, operator-algebras

I was reading a [paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01202103) in which the curvature and Euler characteristic of a completely positive map (in finite dimensions). Let 
\begin{equation}
\Phi(X)=\sum_{j=1}^nV_jXV_j^*
\end{equation}
be a completely positive map such that $\sum_{j=1}^nV_jV_j^*\leq I$ (i.e. a contraction). Then the curvature  is defined as 
\begin{equation}
K(\Phi):=(n-1)\lim_{d\rightarrow\infty}\frac{Tr(I-\Phi^d(I))}{n^d}
\end{equation}
and the Euler characteristic is defined as 
\begin{equation}
\chi(\Phi):=(n-1)\lim_{d\rightarrow\infty}\frac{Rank(I-\Phi^d(I))}{n^d}.
\end{equation}
My problem is, I can not see how the above quantities define the underlying geometry. Further, I am not sure, whether the set of completely positive maps (in finite or infinite dimensions) can form a manifold. I am familiar with Euler characteristic  defined in topology (and graph theory), but can not get the proper intuition to connect it in this scenario. Please help.